# Set value in HTML with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I'm using Angular JS. I loop out a part of a scope that from the start is a JSON array.

I need to check for if a value in that array exists. If it does it should do something. The following code work but I can't figure out a way to save "status" temporary.

```
<div ng-repeat="item_value in item['slug'].values">
    {{item_value}}
    <div ng-if="item_value == 'dogs_cats'">
        Somehow save "status" to true when above is equal.
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="status == 'true'">
    Do someting here.
</div>
```

Maybe my approach is wrong. Maybe this should not go in the template? I like different solutions to choose from and suggestions on which would be prefered.

Comment: Stop approaching this procedural style and start thinking AngularJS :) `ng-show="item_value == 'dogs_cats'"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would do:

```
<div ng-if="item_value == 'dogs_cats'" ng-init="status = true">
    Somehow save "status" to true when above is equal.
</div>
```

But preferably you should put that logic in controller

Comment: {{status}} worked this way, but only inside the first ng-if, not outside of it.

Comment: OK, what's really the status here, what you are trying to achieve?, save the status for current item or global?

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor some of this into a controller. Try something like:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='itemSlugs'>
    <div ng-repeat="item_value in item['slug'].values">
        {{item_value}}
    </div>
    <div ng-if="status">
        Do something here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
    controller('itemSlugs', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.item.slug.values = [ /*initialize here*/ ];
        $scope.status = false;
        $scope.$watch('item.slug.values', function(){
            $scope.status = false;
            $scope.item.slug.values.forEach(function(item_value){
                if (item_value == 'dogs_cats'){
                    $scope.status = true;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I added a watch so if any values in your item.slug.values changes, then the status will update accordingly.